# Populating route with data from JSON in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, routes

I have a working single page app build in AngularJS where I make searches to 3rd party APIs.

The user makes a search query and clicks on one of the displayed results. What I'm attempting to do, is to dinamically create the routes, so when the user selects the resultA from the array of search results, the URL changes to app/#/resultA.

This solution would definitely improve the usability, as the user would be able to go back and forth to previous searches (app/#/resultB back to app/#/resultA).

Here's my services code:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['chieffancypants.loadingBar', 'ngResource', 'ui.bootstrap', 'truncate', 'infinite-scroll'/*, 'QuickList'*/])


  function Ctrl($scope, $http) {

     $scope.$watch('name', function (name){
      if (!name || name.length == 0)
        return 0;
      setTimeout(function() {
        if (name === $scope.name){
          $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/database/search?type=artist&q='+ name +'&page=1&per_page=7', {ignoreLoadingBar: true}).
          success(function(data3) {
            $scope.clicked = false;
            $scope.results = data3.results;
          });
        }
      }, 300);
    });

    $scope.reset = function () {
      $scope.sliding = false;
      $scope.name = undefined;
      $scope.album = undefined;
      $scope.year = undefined;
    }

    $scope.$watch(function() {
        return $scope.artist;
      }, function() {
        if($scope.artist){
          var pos = $scope.artist.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(', the');
          if (pos != -1) {
            $scope.artist.name = 'The ' + $scope.artist.name.slice(0, pos);
          }
        }
      });
    $scope.getTooltipPlacement = function () {
        return ($(window).width() < 768) ? 'top' : 'left';
    };  
    $scope.getDetails = function (id) {
      $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/artists/' + id).
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.artist = data;
            $scope.nextPage = 1;
            $scope.morePages = true;
            $scope.loading = false;
            $scope.releases = [];
            $scope.loadDetails();
            $scope.clicked = true;
            $scope.sliding = true;
        });
    }

    $scope.loadDetails = function(/*quickRepeatList*/) {
          if($scope.morePages && !$scope.loading){
            $scope.loading = true;
            $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/artists/' + $scope.artist.id + '/releases?page=' + $scope.nextPage + '&per_page=8').then(function(data2) {
                $scope.nextPage = $scope.nextPage + 1;
                if($scope.nextPage > data2.data.pagination.pages){
                  $scope.morePages = false;
                }
                $scope.releases = $scope.releases.concat(data2.data.releases);
            }).finally(function(){
              $scope.loading = false;
            });
          }
      };  


  }
    function ImageCtrl($scope, $http) {
          $scope.image = 'img/record-default.png'; 
          $http.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=e8aefa857fc74255570c1ee62b01cdba&artist=' + $scope.artist.name + '&album=' + $scope.release.title + '&format=json', {ignoreLoadingBar: true}).
            success(function (data4) {
              $scope.image = data4.album.image[2]['#text'];
            }
          )

    }
```

The particular function that receives this resultA name, is the following, where $scope.artist would be the string to be added after app/#/:

```
$scope.getDetails = function (id) {
    $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/artists/' + id).
      success(function(data) {
          $scope.artist = data;
          $scope.nextPage = 1;
          $scope.morePages = true;
          $scope.loading = false;
          $scope.releases = [];
          $scope.loadDetails();
          $scope.clicked = true;
          $scope.sliding = true;
      });
  }
```

And a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YtpElwl92nFCRZUTnpqa?p=preview).

Could you point me in the right direction when attempting to manipulate the route with dynamic data?

Comment: so What's your question?

Comment: You're right, wrote too fast : )